# scrollbar of a bottom div appears only when the viewport is smaller than this div, regardless of the another div at the top

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'd like to have header with some flex items in it, meaning the header will have variable height
and then, beneath, I'd like to have a scrollable area that covers the exactly the rest of the browser viewport.

I made some attempts with the following code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <base href="/"
</head>
<body style="height:100vh;overflow:hidden">
    <div>
      Variable height
      <hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr>
    </div>

    <div style="height:100%">
      object
      <div style="height:100%;overflow-y:scroll">
        <ul>
          <li>1</li><li>2</li><li>3</li><li>4</li><li>5</li><li>6</li><li>7</li><li>8</li>
          <li>9</li><li>10</li><li>11</li><li>12</li><li>13</li><li>14</li><li>15</li>
          <li>16</li><li>17</li><li>18</li><li>19</li><li>20</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

but then, when I resize my browser with a smaller height, the scrollbar does not appear when I would expect it to do so:
instead of appearing as long as the lower div is partially clipped out, the scrollbar appears only when the part that is clipped out has the same height as the header.
This problem occurs in chrome and firefox, so I guess I'm not using style properly.

why is it so? why the height of the header has some impact about the overflow of the second div?
is there a proper way to achieve my initial goal, possibly using another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some browsers might put padding or margins in the html and/or body elements, which affects other elements when you try using percentages relative to the viewport dimensions.

I always clear them out.

sample:

```css
html, 
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}

.header {
  flex-grow: 0;
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  white-space: nowrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.header > div {
  padding: 6px;
  flex: 1 1;
}

.scroll-box {
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 6px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="header">
        <div>Variable height</div>
        <div>Variable height</div>
        <div>Variable height</div>
        <div>Variable height</div>
        <div>Variable height</div>
        <div>Variable height</div>
        <div>Variable height</div>
        <div>Variable height</div>
        <div>Variable height</div>
    </div>
    <div class="scroll-box">
        <ul>
          <li>1</li><li>2</li><li>3</li><li>4</li><li>5</li><li>6</li><li>7</li><li>8</li><li>9</li><li>10</li><li>11</li><li>12</li><li>13</li><li>14</li><li>15</li><li>16</li><li>17</li><li>18</li><li>19</li><li>20</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the tip that look helpful in general,
unfortunatly, this is not enough.
it's easier to see when having a bigger header, but the scrollbar is not showing up util the page is clip out a part of the scroll-box div equivalent to the height of the header itself.
and thus, with a small window or a big scroll-box div, scrollbar is not working properly (you cannot get access to the bottom of the div)

Comment: I didn't notice that. Everything should have been in a container. I've updated the answer.